# Suspend to ram fails if NFS active

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

If a process is actively using NFS when I suspend to ram I get:

```
[34174.245400] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
[34174.261634] Filesystems sync: 0.016 seconds
[34174.261917] Freezing user space processes ... 
[34194.267178] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.005 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[34194.267527] task:yt-dlp          state:D stack:    0 pid:387124 ppid:289995 flags:0x00004006
```

If I, however, suspend (CTRL-Z) the process first, everything works: I do not have to kill the process or unmount.

Why? Is there a way I can tell suspend-to-ram to suspend any process it has a problem freezing?

```
$ uname -a
Linux aspire 5.15.0-43-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 12 10:30:17 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the kernel. Is this reproducible with 5.19/Any_supported_stable? If it is, please file a bug report: bugzilla.kernel.org